# How do I let a user see a single bucket in the root s3 console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

What permissions do I set in a policy to allow a user to see a single bucket in the root s3 page in the console (https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets)

I keep trying different things but either they see all the bucketsor none of them.  I gave them permissions to manage the bucket and if they put the bucket url into their browser they can access it fine and upload stuff.  But if they go to the root s3 page it doesn't list any buckets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to control which buckets a user can see listed in the S3 Management Console.

If a user has permission to use the `ListBuckets()` command, then **they will be able to see a listing of *ALL* buckets** in that AWS Account.

However, there is a cheat...

You can give permissions to a user to 'use' a specific Amazon S3 bucket (eg `GetObject`, `PutObject`, `ListObjects`), **while *not* giving them permission *List* the buckets**. They will not be able to use the S3 Management Console to *navigate* to the bucket, but you can give them a URL that will take them *directly* to the bucket in the console, eg:

```
https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/BUCKET-NAME
```

This will let them see and use the bucket in the S3 Management Console, but they won't be able to see the names of any other buckets and they won't be able to navigate to their bucket via the 'root s3 page' that you mention. Instead, they will need to use that URL.